# CSS UL Menu issues when I resize the page

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I'm new with CSS and I'm having some problems with UL Menu.
Here is the code:

```
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    font-family:Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;  
}
#header{
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black; 
}
.container{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width:63%;
    height:60px;s
}
#nameArea{
    width:18%;
    height:60px;
    margin-left:2%;
    color:white;

    float:left;
}
#nameArea label{
    line-height:50px;   
    font-size:20px;
}
#menuArea{
    width:58%;
    height:60px;
    float:right;
    position: relative;

}
#menuArea ul{
    position: fixed;
    list-style:none;

}
#menuArea li{
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    margin-left:30px;
}
#menuArea a{
    text-decoration:none;

    color:#B7B7B7;  
}
#menuArea a:hover{
    color:white;    
}
```

It works when the page is maximized but when I try to resize the page it goes crazy. I tried without `position: relative` too. Any ideas?

Edit: Here is my HTML code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<div id = "header">
    <div class="container"> 
        <div id="nameArea">
            <label> namerandom </label>
        </div>
        <div id="menuArea">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
            </ul>                                                            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz8jverk/)

Comment: Post a complete code example please, including your HTML.

Comment: Do what @j08691 asked for or create [DEMO](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @xVinz, So what do you want when page re-sized(window width decreased)?

Comment: I would that menu doesn't go in another line, like if I put a <br>! I want something other, I don't really know what, but not this !
Any ideas? Sorry, I'm really newbie. Thanks